# XSL 1.0: Identity transform that skips elements where an attribute is empty

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am looking to modify the identity transform to skip elements, where any of the attribute is empty, e.g.:
copy `<anyElement anyAttr1="a" anyAttr2="b"/>`
but do not copy `<anotherElement anotherAttr1="a" anotherAttr2=""/>`

Notes:

1. It does not matter if an element has children or not.
2. Elements with no attributes at all (container elements) should be copied

Source example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parameterset>
    <Type Code=""/>
    <Inventory Code="250" Index="0"/>
    <Inventory Code="350" Index=""/>
</Parameterset>
```

Transformed example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parameterset>
    <Inventory Code="250" Index="0"/>       
</Parameterset>
```

All I could come up with was:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*[. != '']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

, but this only removes the empty attributes and still copies the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:template match="*[@*[. =  '']]"/>` to remove those elements or `<xsl:template match="*[@*[. =  '']]"><xsl:apply-templates></xsl:template>` to only process their contents. Of course those templates work together with the identity transformation template.